# Parse relative URI

Tags: .net, uri

I'd like to extract the query string and fragment from a relative URI, that is, a URI without any scheme or host information.

Is there a more elegant way to do this than by turning it into an absolute URI with a fake host name?

```
var relativeUri = "/dir1/dir2/file?a=b&c=d#fragment";
var uri = new Uri(new Uri("http://example.com"), relativeUri);
var path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(String.Concat(uri.Segments));
var query = uri.Query;
var fragment = uri.Fragment;
// path = "/dir1/dir2/file", query = "?a=b&c=d", fragment = "#fragment"
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Although you can create a `Uri` without a host portion, most of its properties will then throw an InvalidOperationException (*"This operation is not supported for a relative URI"*) because those properties rely on an absolute Uri.

[`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.100).aspx) is indeed not going to help here, because it only operates on the query part of an Uri, which you cannot obtain because you don't have an absolute Uri.

So although it might seem hacky, I think the `new Uri(baseUri, relativeUri)` contstructor does exactly what you want. I cannot seem to find a better or cleaner way to accomplish the same.

Comment: Actually, `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()` works with relative URLs as well. A little late to the party - but was checking something similar :)

Comment: @Nomad I'm afraid it doesn't. `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("/dir1/dir2/file?a=b&c=d#fragment");` yields two results: `/dir1/dir2/file?a = b` and `c = d#fragment`, which is absolutely not what you're interested in. You really need to pass it a query string only.

Comment: 10 years later and this is still good advice. I just inserted a fake `https://host` in front of the relative URL and everything magically worked.

Answer (score 6):

Running into this issue myself i found that `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` is really only looking for a string and anything after the '?'

so being that i have to use this in both cases (relative and absolute) I find the following seems to work quite well

```
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url.Split('?').Last())
```